# Display list of posts for specific users dynamically Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, posts

I wanted to show list of custom posts (post type=property) for every specific user, all of his posts at single place, for example:
I have a 3 users in my wordpress:

1. test1
2. test2
3. test3

so what I want is `example.com/properties/test1` should show all of posts published by 'test1' user.
similarly for: test2 and test3.

I have custom template created using html/css/js for displaying posts but I am not getting a way to display them dynamically with there username in url.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the username in the url, look into changing the .htaccess file to redirect the /test1 to currentfile.php?username=test1 then you can get the username from $_GET['username']

Comment: Thanks @victor-svensson can you please tell me what should I write in .htaccess file to get that redirect?

Comment: Im not great at htaccess files but try adding the following:
 
RewriteRule ^properties/(.*)$ page_to_use.php?user_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L] 

Found this example at https://www.quora.com/How-change-website-url-via-htaccess-for-php